# Persist existing data when add new object in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My data is:

```js
const a = [{
    name: "a"
}, {
    name: "b"
}, {
    name: "c"
}]
```

and I want to add new object `{name:"d"}` in already existing data
(which is added dynamically on onchange `{name: onchangedata?.value}` ).

For that I'm doing: `[...a,{name:"d"} ]`. But after that I want to add  new object again that is `{name:"e"}`, but it's replaced with last added object which is `{name:"d"}`. Instead of this I want final result after adding `{name:"e"}` that is:

```js
[{
    name: "a"
}, {
    name: "b"
}, {
    name: "c"
}, {
    name: "d"
}, {
    name: "e"
}]
```

I've used spread operator but it's not returning expected data. I don't know where is my mistake.

I have used concat also:
`{...a?.concat({name: onchangedata?.value})}`

Comment: There are no guarantees an array's items will be in the order you want them in, so sort the array in the desired order before accessing.

Comment: But my main  issue is when onchange fire ,new object is replaced with lastly added object

Comment: Please share a [mre] of the code which exhibits the issue.

Comment: show your entire code related to this situation, not just the data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.